# Batch Remembering Configuration

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch code to remember user input. Like if you put in "echo What is your name?" then put in your name. It would then save it somewhere to remember it or recall it later on. Even if it were to create and write it to a file to remember things from.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `set /?`, pay particular attention to the `/P` option.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`@echo off
cls
set INPUT= 
set /P INPUT=Input your name (it will be logged in names.txt): %=%
echo Your inputted name was: %INPUT%
echo %INPUT%  >>names.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of using Windows batch commands to write user input to a file. Note the file will be written in the same directory you run the batch file from.

```
set /p name="What is your name: "
@echo off
echo %name% > name.txt
```

The /p flag turns this into a prompt, setting the value of name to the result of the user input string. @echo off prevents echoing the next line, which echoes the stored variable into a text file called name.txt. If name.txt doesn't exist, it's created; if it does exist, it's overwritten with this value.